# WPF 508 Compliance

Tags: wpf, accessibility, section508

Are there any good guides on making WPF applications 508 compliant? For example, does every text input box need to be associated with a label via some tag type like with webpages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [this white paper](http://windowsclient.net/wpf/white-papers/wpf-app-quality-guide.aspx) at [WindowsClient.net](http://windowsclient.net/) that appears to contain guidelines.

There is also [this pdf](http://download.infragistics.com/marketing/netadvantage/net/vpat-wpf.pdf) about accesibility in Infragistics' WPF controls. It may contain some clues, but it is in the context of custom controls rather than entire UIs.

Answer (score 1):

I find [Engineering Software for Accessibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dd936223.aspx) portal page very useful, as it covers all aspects of the accessible application development - with a handful of links to MSDN pages.